# Flutter Horizontal PageView with Child Width Larger Screen Width

Tags: flutter, flutter-pageview

How to implement PageView width child have width larger screen width.

```
PageView(
      controller: controller,
      children: const <Widget>[
       Image('img1.jpg'),
       Image('img2.jpg'),  // large image one
       Image('img3.jpg')
      ],
)
```

https://i.imgur.com/jvowQd2.mp4

Answer (score 0):

try using `InteractiveViewer`. It lets you have a bigger size image or widget in it and the user can zoom or zoom out from it.
[InteractiveViewer](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InteractiveViewer-class.html) documentation.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but the width of child page smaller or equal with screen width, I have to pan or zoom with InteractiveViewer.

Comment: you can change its setting to be of the original size.

Comment: you can set `constraints = false`